# How to not overwrite a value of a dictionary when taking and storing a user's input? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a python beginner tried making a contact book/address book program. I take a user input/contact info(value) and store it as a value to a dictionary, however while the program still running if I try to enter a new contact info(new value) it will overwrite the existing one, how do I solve this? so I can add as many contact info(value) as I want while the program still running.

Thanks in advance.

this is my code:

```
def head():
    print("")
    print("========================")
    print("      Contact Book      ")
    print("========================")

def restart():
    response = input("\nOpen menu again? (yes/no): ").lower()
    if response == "yes":
        task()
    else:
        print("\nSee You next time!")

def task():
    head()
    done = False
    print('''1. Add Contact
2. Search
3. View Contact List
4. Delete All Contact
5. Exit''')
    while not done:
        task = input("\nWhat do You want to do? (1-5):")
        if task == "1":
            print("\nAdding a new contact!")
            global cnt_lst
            global new
            cnt_lst = {}  
            new = {}
            new['new_key'] = {}
            new['new_key']['Name '] = input("Name: ")
            new['new_key']['Phone'] = input("Phone: ")
            if not new['new_key']['Phone'].isnumeric():
                while not new['new_key']['Phone'].isnumeric():
                        print("Invalid input, please enter only a number!")
                        new['new_key']['Phone'] = input("Phone: ")
            new['new_key']['Email'] = input("Email: ")
            cnt_lst.update(new)
            print("\nContact is saved!")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "2":
            search = input("\nSearch: ")
            info = False

            for key, value in cnt_lst.items():   
                for npe, val in value.items():
                    if search in val:
                        info = True
                        print("=" * 20)
                        for npe, val in value.items():
                            print(npe,' : ',val)
                        break

            if not info:
                print("\nNo info was found!")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "3":
            if 'cnt_lst' not in globals():
                print("\nNo contact info available!")
            elif 'cnt_lst' in globals() and len(cnt_lst) == 0:
                print("\nNo contact info available!")
            else:
                print("\nAll Contact Info")
                for key, value in cnt_lst.items():   
                    for npe, val in value.items():
                        print("=" * 20)
                        for npe, val in value.items():
                            print(npe,' : ',val)
                        break
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "4":
            cnt_lst.clear()
            print("\nSuccesfully deleted all contact info!")
            done = True
            restart()

        elif task == "5":
            print("See You next time!")
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid input please enter a single number from 1 to 5")
            restart()
   
task()
```

Comment: hi, perhaps store the items in a list `contacts=[]; newContact={'name': 'Name'}; contacts.append(newContact)`

Comment: Note that if the user input is not a character in the range 1-5 your functions will run recursively. That's almost certainly not what you want. Also consider constructing a dictionary in your main program (before you call task()) then pass its reference to the task() function

Comment: hi thanks for all your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that every time your user press 1 to input a new contact your code goes like this:

```py
print("\nAdding a new contact!")
            global cnt_lst
            global new
            cnt_lst = {}  # <- here you are erasing your dictionary
            new = {}
```

You should store your dictionary for example as a text file or XML or JSON so all the contacts are stored localy and then at the start of your program you can read its contents for printing or adding new entries

Comment: Or for troubleshooting just declare this dictionary globaly outside the while loop